# Writing old dates to a Delta table using Pyspark throws an error, even when using the recommended datetimeRebaseModeInWrite configuration

Tags: python, pyspark, delta-lake, gregorian-calendar

Writing to Delta table in Python - error writing very old dates.

I am trying to write some updates to a Delta table on S3. For this I am using the Python [delta-spark](https://pypi.org/project/delta-spark/) package.

When trying to run a `merge` statement, the job crashes. The error is due to Spark 3.0 making the change to use Proleptic Gregorian calendar instead of hybrid Gregorian+Julian calendar, which might cause [incompatibilities when reading very old dates.](https://www.projectpro.io/recipes/handle-writing-dates-before-1582-10-15-or-timestamps-before-1900-01-01t-00-00-00z-into-parquet-files).

The suggestion I've found in several places is to set the following Spark config: `.config("spark.sql.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")`. However, this throws the following error, which also seems to be date related:

```
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:513)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage5.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.writeWithIterator(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1538)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:338)
    ... 9 more
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.$anonfun$writeFiles$1(TransactionalWrite.scala:398)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand.$anonfun$writeAllChanges$1(MergeIntoCommand.scala:930)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand.recordMergeOperation(MergeIntoCommand.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand.writeAllChanges(MergeIntoCommand.scala:655)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand.$anonfun$runMerge$4(MergeIntoCommand.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.DeltaProgressReporter.withJobDescription(DeltaProgressReporter.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.DeltaProgressReporter.withStatusCode(DeltaProgressReporter.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.DeltaProgressReporter.withStatusCode$(DeltaProgressReporter.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand.withStatusCode(MergeIntoCommand.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand.$anonfun$runMerge$2(MergeIntoCommand.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand.$anonfun$runMerge$2$adapted(MergeIntoCommand.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.withNewTransaction(DeltaLog.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand.$anonfun$runMerge$1(MergeIntoCommand.scala:363)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile(DeltaLogging.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile$(DeltaLogging.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand.recordFrameProfile(MergeIntoCommand.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.$anonfun$recordDeltaOperationInternal$1(DeltaLogging.scala:133)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksLogging.scala:128)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksLogging.recordOperation$(DatabricksLogging.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand.recordOperation(MergeIntoCommand.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperationInternal(DeltaLogging.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation$(DeltaLogging.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand.recordDeltaOperation(MergeIntoCommand.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand.runMerge(MergeIntoCommand.scala:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand.$anonfun$run$1(MergeIntoCommand.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.merge.MergeIntoMaterializeSource.runWithMaterializedSourceLostRetries(MergeIntoMaterializeSource.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.merge.MergeIntoMaterializeSource.runWithMaterializedSourceLostRetries$(MergeIntoMaterializeSource.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand.runWithMaterializedSourceLostRetries(MergeIntoCommand.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.MergeIntoCommand.run(MergeIntoCommand.scala:356)
    at io.delta.tables.DeltaMergeBuilder.$anonfun$execute$1(DeltaMergeBuilder.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.AnalysisHelper.improveUnsupportedOpError(AnalysisHelper.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.AnalysisHelper.improveUnsupportedOpError$(AnalysisHelper.scala:91)
    at io.delta.tables.DeltaMergeBuilder.improveUnsupportedOpError(DeltaMergeBuilder.scala:148)
    at io.delta.tables.DeltaMergeBuilder.execute(DeltaMergeBuilder.scala:266)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.taskFailedWhileWritingRowsError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$21(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow
    at java.lang.Math.multiplyExact(Math.java:892)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.millisToMicros(DateTimeUtils.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.RebaseDateTime$.rebaseGregorianToJulianMicros(RebaseDateTime.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.RebaseDateTime$.rebaseGregorianToJulianMicros(RebaseDateTime.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.RebaseDateTime$.rebaseGregorianToJulianMicros(RebaseDateTime.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.toJavaTimestamp(DateTimeUtils.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils.toJavaTimestamp(DateTimeUtils.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificSafeProjection.createExternalRow_0_4$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificSafeProjection.CreateExternalRow_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificSafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:486)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:513)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage5.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.writeWithIterator(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1538)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:338)
    ... 9 more
```

I am not sure how to proceed here, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you